# Mysql SUM single condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query statement likes:

```
`SELECT 
SUM(outBytes), 
timestamp FROM vts_hosts 
WHERE host IN ('a','b', 'c') 
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 1000 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC;`
```

actually, I just want to `SUM` `outBytes` of single host, how to???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this query if you only want sum of outBytes :

SELECT SUM(outBytes) FROM vts_hosts WHERE host IN ('a','b', 'c') GROUP BY host

Comment: What if I `SUM` (SUM(outBytes), SUM(inBytes), ...) multi column ??

Comment: I suspect by 'single host', @khu